Error Invalid channel create transaction : bad header Anchor peer update failed while running sample chaincode on hyperledger-fabric
I am working with hyperledger for the first time and When I am trying to run the sample chaincode provided by the hyperledger-fabric, I am using the chaincode in Javascript.
First it is showing channel is created.
Then Using organization 1
Fetching channel config for channel mychannel
Generating anchor peer update transaction for Org1 on channel mychannel
jq: command not found
and lastly
configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error decoding input: error unmarshaling intermediate JSON: EOF
2024-04-23 17:51:30.536 IST 0001 INFO [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: Invalid channel create transaction : bad header
Anchor peer update failed
Please help me with this
I do not know exactly what to try

Hello, welcome to SO! It would help potential answerers if you can post a simplified version of your code. This way, people would have a more concrete place to start their answers from.
